# Using CASE WHEN with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

Background: I'm trying to display a table with the headings: id, full_name, position_7, position_8, position_9...etc if a person was an active employee for Jul and Aug, then 2012_Jul and 2012_Aug will be displayed in position_7 and 8 on one line. If I don't use GROUP BY I get the output but on 2 lines. The reason this is happening is because in the BLMths table a single person will have multiple entries due to being employed for more than 1 month.

The below query will get every persons id, full_name and month successfully...if I don't use GROUP BY. But the problem is, if I neglect to use GROUP BY I will have 4 lines (or more) for each person in my table.   When I do use GROUP BY, I have the desired output of 1 line for each person, but the data I need in the table isn't all there.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Or does anyone know why when I use GROUP BY the data from some of my CASE statements appear to be missing?

I know the answer to this has to be simple, but I can't seem to solve it.  Any help is appreciated.   Many thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Blm.Ags, Blmths.Id, Ie.Full_Name, Blmths.Month,
       CASE month
       WHEN "2012-07-01" THEN 1
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_7,
       CASE month
       WHEN "2012-08-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_8,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2012-09-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_9,
       CASE month
       WHEN "2012-10-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_10,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2012-11-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_11,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2012-12-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_12,
       CASE month
       WHEN '2013-01-01' THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_1,
       CASE month
       WHEN "2013-02-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_2,
       CASE month
       WHEN "2012-03-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_3,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2013-04-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_4,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2013-05-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_5,
       CASE Blmths.Month
       WHEN "2013-06-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Position_6
  FROM Bogus_Leadership_Months AS Blmths, Injection_Employees AS Ie,
Bogus_Leadership_Members AS Blm
  WHERE Blmths.Id = Blm.Id
    AND Ie.Ags = Blm.Ags
    AND Ie.Centre_Id = '666'
  GROUP BY Blm.Ags
```

Comment: I'm trying to display a table that looks like this:

Comment: @KahlilN: Please do not put such information into comments, edit your question instead. And please review existing answers and give feedback if they work, or what is wrong with them.

Comment: @PeterLang - Thanks for your advice.  I've edited the question and removed the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific. What database is this against? In what way did it not work? Did an error occur or did it not return the results you required? What does ' the data I need in the table isn't all there' mean?

What happens if there is more than one record per person, how do you want to **aggregate** the data?

I'm guessing you *might* want something along these lines (shortened):

```
SELECT Blm.Ags, Blmths.Id, Ie.Full_Name,
   SUM(CASE Blmths.month
   WHEN "2012-07-01" THEN 1
       ELSE NULL
   END) AS Position_7
FROM Bogus_Leadership_Months AS Blmths, Injection_Employees AS Ie,
Bogus_Leadership_Members AS Blm
  WHERE Blmths.Id = Blm.Id
    AND Ie.Ags = Blm.Ags
    AND Ie.Centre_Id = '666'
  GROUP BY Blm.Ags, Blmths.Id, Ie.Full_Name
```

This gives a tally of that person by month.

I can't see the example of the data you're after - could you repost it?

Comment: I'm using MYSQL and a few errors occurred with the query below. I started getting the error "Unknown column in field list", when i got past that I was getting "Unknown column GRPBYCOL in 'group statement'". All that aside, the above query is **EXACTLY** what I was trying to do and it works **PERFECTLY!**  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT max(Blmths.Id), Ie.Full_Name, Blmths.Month,Blm.Ags FROM 
    (SELECT Blm.Ags,Blmths.Id, Ie.Full_Name, Blmths.Month 
    CASE month
           WHEN "2012-07-01" THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_7,
           CASE month
           WHEN "2012-08-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_8,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2012-09-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_9,
           CASE month
           WHEN "2012-10-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_10,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2012-11-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_11,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2012-12-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_12,
           CASE month
           WHEN '2013-01-01' THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_1,
           CASE month
           WHEN "2013-02-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_2,
           CASE month
           WHEN "2012-03-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_3,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2013-04-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_4,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2013-05-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_5,
           CASE Blmths.Month
           WHEN "2013-06-01" THEN Date_Format(Blmths.Month, '%Y_%b')
               ELSE NULL
           END AS Position_6
      FROM Bogus_Leadership_Months AS Blmths, Injection_Employees AS Ie,
    Bogus_Leadership_Members AS Blm
      WHERE Blmths.Id = Blm.Id
        AND Ie.Ags = Blm.Ags
        AND Ie.Centre_Id = '666') AS GRPBYCOL 
   GROUP BY  Ie.Full_Name, Blmths.Month,Blm.Ags,GRPBYCOL
```